# Why can we say "couldn't here" and not "could not"?

Tags: meaning, usage

1. Couldn't you explain this just one more time? [Source](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/could-modals#:%7E:text=%27Could%27%20is%20used%20to%20express,at%20the%20age%20of%20six.)
2. David couldn’t have the money. It is not possible that David has the money. [Source](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/could-modals#:%7E:text=%27Could%27%20is%20used%20to%20express,at%20the%20age%20of%20six.)

How can the first one be a request?
Please show me some examples of these two sentences.

Comment: The two sentences _are_ examples, provided by the website you link to. The second one could also be expressed as _David can't [possibly] have the money_.

Comment: I tried to edit your title but not sure I really understood your question.  If you can explain it better, edit it again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is request because of it's question mark and the fact that the question is *directed* to "you" in this case.

More examples are:

> You couldn’t stop at a bank machine, could you?

> Why couldn't you give me the money earlier?

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/requests

As you can see, the have question marks and direct the question/request to someone, usually "you" - therefore *implies* that it is a request

Other general uses of "couldn't":

> I was so excited that I couldn't sleep, so I got up and dressed.

> I couldn't see a thing earlier.

Comment: "The first one is **a** request because of **its** question mark"

Comment: @DialFrost Isn't it your responsibility to find them yourself?

Comment: I mean, I could find them myself, just that I do not have the time @Eden0516

Comment: @Eden0516 You can simply edit my post to add the attribution if you know the link, I would gladly approve the edit (gotube has helped me edit and add attributions)

Comment: Why should I help you edit it? You did something incorrect, and others have to help you deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

In many societies, it is considered more polite and respectful to say some things indirectly. The first sentence you quoted is an example of that. If you said something like

> Hey, you, explain it again!

it would be considered quite direct and quite blunt, maybe even impolite or rude.

To be more polite, you can state your request indirectly. You don't spell out the request, but you ask why the other person can't honor your request. The implied train of thought is something like this

> (You) Couldn't you explain this just one more time?

> (The other person) Yes, I could.

> (You) So would you explain it, please?

So your first example actually isn't a request with regard to the literal meaning and the grammatical structure, but it is implied that it is meant to be a request.